# lblBox Returns zero after assigning lstBox selected item using .ToString("P0") and .TrimEnd

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a simple program, the textbook want me to use the string.TrimStart() and string.TrimEnd() methods within the program.  You input your amount into txtSales, then select the appropriate sales tax within lstRates, press the calculate button and it calculates how much tax you are charged and displays it in lblTax.  Now, seems no matter what method i use do do this, lstRates always returns 0..  Any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtSales_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSales.Enter
    txtSales.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub lstRates_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstRates.SelectedValueChanged
    lblTax.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub txtSales_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSales.TextChanged
    lblTax.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' fills the list box with tax rates

    For dblRate As Double = 0.02 To 0.1 Step 0.01
        lstRates.Items.Add(dblRate.ToString("P0"))
    Next dblRate
    lstRates.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim dblSales As Double
    Dim dblRates As Double
    Dim strRates As String

    Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, dblSales)
    strRates = lstRates.Text
    strRates = strRates.TrimEnd("%"c)
    Double.TryParse(strRates, dblRates)
    Double.TryParse(lstRates.Text, dblRates)

    lblTax.Text = (dblSales * dblRates).ToString

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `Double.TryParse(lstRates.Text, dblRates)` is overwriting the result from the line above it.  if you arent going to check the Parse, you could use `Double.Parse` - tryParse returns a Boolean indicating whether it could parse a value or not.  In your case the second one fails (because of the '%' from Text), and stores 0.0 in dblRates. should be easy to see under Debug

Comment: hahaha guess i havent had enough coffee today, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted Double.TryParse(lstRates.Text, dblRates) and added dblRates *= 0.01
Works like a charm!

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim dblSales As Double
    Dim dblRates As Double
    Dim strRates As String

    Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, dblSales)
    strRates = lstRates.Text
    strRates = strRates.TrimEnd("%"c)
    Double.TryParse(strRates, dblRates)
    dblRates *= 0.01


    lblTax.Text = (dblSales * dblRates).ToString("C2")

End Sub
```